# How to show that $f(x,y)=\dfrac{\left(x+y\right)\left(x+y+1\right)}{2}+y$ is injective (one-to-one) from $\textbf{N}^2$ to $\textbf{N}$

Tags: calculus, functions

How to show $$f(x,y)=\dfrac{\left(x+y\right)\left(x+y+1\right)}{2}+y$$ is injective (one-to-one) from $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: this was certainly asked before here and it is also called the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function)

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1078689p4726690

Comment: Also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/127695/11619) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/665774/11619).

Comment: And please check out [the abridged guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619) for ways to make sure your questions won't attract negative attention.

Comment: thanks a lot!

good luck to me explaining this to a high school student !!

Comment: You can explain how this function emerges in a countability proof $\Bbb{N}^2$ when you list pairs of numbers $(x,y)$ one diagonal at a time (sorted primarily according to the sum $x+y$ and secondarily according to $y$).